# What is the correct mgcv syntax for interacting a smooth with an interaction of linear predictors?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, smoothing, mgcv

I have a question about `mgcv`'s formula syntax for interactions with smooths `s()` (I am actually using this syntax within `brms`).

Say I have two interacting factors `X1` and `X2` and I want to estimate how this interaction is moderated by a smoothed term `X3` (a "varying coefficients" model). According to the `mgcv` help, when the `by` variable is a factor, it should be included as a main effect, but I am not sure how that applies when the interaction term is also a `by` variable. So, would I write that as

```
Y ~ X1 * X2 + s(X3, by=X1) + s(X3, by=X2) + s(X3, by=interaction(X1,X2))
```

or as

```
Y ~ X1 * X2 + s(X3, by=interaction(X1,X2))
```

Now, to get to the heart of my question, let us suppose that `X2` is a continuous predictor, not a factor (according to the `mgcv` help, when the `by` variable is a continuous predictor, it should *not* be included as a main effect). So, which would be the correct syntax

```
Y ~ X1 + s(X3, by=X1) + s(X3, by=X2) + s(X3, by=interaction(X1,X2))
```

or

```
Y - X1 + s(X3, by=interaction(X1,X2))
```

or are both wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the two factors, I would use the second form

```r
df <- transform(df, X1X2 = interaction(X1, X2, drop = TRUE))
Y ~ X1 * X2 + s(X3, by = X1X2)
```

(where `df` is the object passed to `data`.) You need to be careful with `interaction()` creating all possible combinations rather than the combinations in the data.

I might even go so far as doing

```r
df <- transform(df, X1X2 = factor(paste(X1, X2, sep = '_')))
Y ~ X1 * X2 + s(X3, by = X1X2)
```

The terms produced by the intercept, `X1`, and `X2` will code for the means of each group, while `X1X2` should give a factor also coding for each group such that we get a smooth for each combination of `X1` and `X2`. It doesn't really matter how the group means get code, just so long as we have a unique factor for each combination of them and have this coded in the dataset. The smooths and the factor fixed effects in the formula are somewhat independent in how we represent the effects in the model; so long as we get a smooth per unique combination *and* we represent the group means in some way we are good.

I'm not sure it is strictly possible to do what you want with a continuous `X2`. This came up recently on Twitter and there Eric Pedersen suggested

```r
Y ~ X1 + te(X3, X2, bs = c('cr', 're'), by = X1)
```

which would give a tensor product of a cubic regression spline in `X3` and a random slope (i.e. a linear effect) of `X2`.

In the Twitter conversation where Eric suggested that solution, the only other way we could think to do it would be by writing a new `smooth.construct` function that would simply add an unpenalized, linear term to the model matrix. But no one went so far as to implement that as yet.

Comment: Thank you. I am unsure what the "coefficients" would mean in `Y ~ X1 * X2 + s(X3, by = X1X2)`. Suppose `X1` and `X2` each have 2 levels and are dummy coded; for the following 4 possible cases of `X1` and `X2`, are the these predictions correctly specified:

for $X1=0$, $X2=0$, predictions are $b_0 + f(X3)$;

for $X1=1$, $X2=0$, predictions are $b_0 + b_{X1} + f(X3)$;

for $X1=0$, $X2=1$, predictions are $b_0 + b_{X2} + f(X3)$;

for $X1=X2=1$, predictions are $b_0 + b_{X1} + b_{X2} + b_{X1X2} + f(X3)$?

So, in each case, it is the same `X3` "curve", just differently offset?

Comment: No, the model now has $f_j(X3)$ where $j$ indexes the levels of `X1X2`. Each of the $j$ smooths has it's own smoothness parameter, so the smooths can have different wiggliness. Basically the model matrix gets $j$ x `k` new columns, whose values are all 0 *except* for the rows related to the $j$th smooth, ie whose combination of `X1` and `X2` is that of the $j$th group. The parametric terms for `X1` and `X2` do shift the curve up and down; the $j$ smooths are centred so we need these terms to get the group means. But this model also specifies $j$ separate smooths.

Comment: Multiple separate smooths -- excellent, now I understand (I was mentally multiplying instead of concatenating and so incorrectly thinking `X1X2` had just two levels)! In the last formula `Y ~ X1 + te(X3, X2, bs = c('cr', 're'), by = X1)`, I don't yet understand how the `'re'` argument turns `X2` into a slope (a penalized linear effect) but I think having these slopes penalized makes sense in my current use case, so this is a good solution. For `X3`, is there any reason to prefer `'cr'` over, for example, `'tp'`?

Comment: For the random effect basis `bs = 're'`, the mgcv-convention is to add random intercept for a factor variable or a random (linear) slope for a continuous variable. However, as you are only passing the one continuous variable you simply get a shrunk linear coefficient. When you do a tensor product of this with a smooth function, the effect is to have the shrunk linear coefficient for `X2` vary as a smooth function of  `X3`. A cubic regression spline basis is the default in `te()` so I just used that, because you have to provide something for the first marginal smooth.